# Pyspark - Merge struct columns into array

Tags: struct, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to merge multiple struct columns into an array.

I tried array(col1, col2) from .. but it ended up with data type mismatch even though all the struct column are of the same type.

Query ->

`select array(struct(f_name_add, True as is_data_found),struct(l_name_add, True as is_data_found)) as tag from (select array(map('value',f_name),map('value',f_add)) as f_name_add, array(map('value',l_name),map('value',l_add)) as l_name_add from (select distinct f_name, f_add, l_name, l_add from db.tabl1 where id = 'aaa')`

Input

```
Sample Table

 id   f_name  f_add  l_name  l_add

 aaa  tom    in     nats    in
```

Expected output:

```
"tag":
 [
       {
            "f_name_add": [
                {
                    "value":"tom"
                },
                {
                    "value": "in"
                }
            ],
            "is_data_found": true
        },
        {
         "l_name_add": [
                {
                    "value":"nats"
                },
                {
                    "value": "in"
                }
            ],
            "is_data_found": true
        }
]
```

Error :

`cannot resolve 'array(named_struct('f_name_add', __auto_generated_subquery_name.`f_name_add`, 'is_data_found', true), named_struct('l_name_add', __auto_generated_subquery_name.`l_name_add`, 'is_data_found', true))' due to data type mismatch: input to function array should all be the same type, but it's [struct<f_name_add:array<map<string,string>>,is_data_found:boolean>, struct<l_name_add:array<map<string,string>>,is_data_found:boolean>]`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error message says there are two `struct`s:
`struct<f_name_add:array<map<string,string>>` vs. `struct<l_name_add:array<map<string,string>>`.

They don't compare equal to each other due to the `f_name_add` and `l_name_add`.

Here I'll try to create an array of json strings, I am not sure that's exactly what you want though :(

1. Setup a simple example

```
a = [('aaa', 'tom', 'in', 'nats', 'in'),('bbb', 'tom1', 'on', 'nats1', 'on'),]
df = spark.createDataFrame(a, ['id', 'f_name',  'f_add',  'l_name', 'l_add'])
df.show()


+---+------+-----+------+-----+
| id|f_name|f_add|l_name|l_add|
+---+------+-----+------+-----+
|aaa|   tom|   in|  nats|   in|
|bbb|  tom1|   on| nats1|   on|
+---+------+-----+------+-----+
```

2. Here's the algo:

```
df.registerTempTable("tabl1")
df = spark.sql("select array(to_json(struct(f_name_add, True as is_data_found)), \
                             to_json(struct(l_name_add, True as is_data_found))) as tag \
                from (select array(map('value',f_name),map('value',f_add)) as f_name_add, \
                       array(map('value',l_name),map('value',l_add)) as l_name_add \
                from (select distinct f_name, f_add, l_name, l_add from tabl1 where id = 'aaa'))")

df.show(truncate=False)

+------------------------+
|tag                                                                                                                                          |
+------------------------+
|[{"f_name_add":[{"value":"tom"},{"value":"in"}],"is_data_found":true}, {"l_name_add":[{"value":"nats"},{"value":"in"}],"is_data_found":true}]|
+------------------------+
```

If you run `df.dtypes`, We'll have and you can see that we actually have an array of json strings here.

```
[('tag', 'array<string>')]
```

Comment: Yes, Any thoughts on how I could overcome this ? May be a UDF or any hints could be helpful.

Comment: Do you have some sample data? and best with sample output. that'll be easier for people to help here :)

Comment: Added sample input and expected output

Comment: How many unique values like ‘f_name_add’ and ‘l_name_add’ do you have there?

Comment: It can be any number as it is dynamic and depends on the input

Comment: are you suggesting there can be a lot of values like 'f_name' and 'f_add' etc? If so, you may want to store the values in row, instead of adding columns for additional 'f_name', 'f_add'. That may demand different algorithms.

Comment: @Nats see my edited answer. As I mentioned above, it feels like the 'f_name' things should in row, not in column names. Anyway, that's a try. Hope it helps.